# Example of high availability voting tactic

Tags: architecture

As I read in *Software Architecture in Practice* by Len Bass, Paul Clements and Rick Kazman about availability voting tactic, the definition of voting tactic in fault recovery is:

> Processes running on redundant processors each take equivalent input and compute a simple output value that is sent to a voter. If the voter detects deviant behavior from a single processor, it fails it. The voting algorithm can be "majority rules" or "preferred component" or some other algorithm. This method is used to correct faulty operation of algorithms or failure of a processor and is often used in control systems. If all of the processors utilize the same algorithms, the redundancy detects only a processor fault and not an algorithm fault. Thus, if the consequence of a failure is extreme, such as potential loss of life, the redundant components can be diverse.
>
> One extreme of diversity is that the software for each redundant component is developed by different teams and executes on dissimilar platforms. Less extreme is to develop a single software component on dissimilar platforms. Diversity is expensive to develop and maintain and is used only in exceptional circumstances, such as the control of surfaces on aircraft. It is usually used for control systems in which the outputs to the voter are straightforward and easy to classify as equivalent or deviant, the computations are cyclic, and all redundant components receive equivalent inputs from sensors. Diversity has no downtime when a failure occurs since the voter continues to operate. Variations on this approach include the Simplex approach, which uses the results of a "preferred" component unless they deviate from those of a "trusted" component, to which it defers. Synchronization among the redundant components is automatic since they are all assumed to be computing on the same set of inputs in parallel.

Could anybody tell me some examples of this tactic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space shuttle flight control computers used voting, as far as I know, to determine which output to use. They could all vote for or against each other. If all four systems came up with different answers, all voting each other out, a backup flight computer which was not built on the same platform as the four primaries would take over for them. You can easily google the details.